# Can't see grub menu at all! Shift doesn't work!

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I changed my grub timeout to 0. And now I can't access Ubuntu at all! Any help? I have no access to Windows 7. Currently I am using a USB version of Ubuntu. Shift doesn't work either I tried every single way possible! And I've read other answers, when they say do these commands, I do all but when I get to `sudo update-grub` I get an error message that it can't find the drive, or something like that! Please help! Not sure which grub. But the newest Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys doesn't work at boot when you want to go in grub menu, you should edit again `/etc/default/grub` file (with `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` command from terminal) and revert the changes you have made (set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`).

After this, if you want that the changes to take effect, run next command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If the above method still doesn't work, try to use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).